# How to convert a python file with packages in it, into exe file

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a python file into an exe file, but in the file there are packages used in it.So how to convert an python file with packages in it, into exe file?

I am using auto-py-to-exe to convert a python file into an exe file

Comment: What is the output of the pyinstaller command that is generated by auto-py-to-exe? And what do you mean by "packages"? Are you experiencing any error in particular? If so, you should [edit] your question to include it here